# how to create endless video autoplay in javascript and vimeo api?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, vimeo, ajaxform

I am a little bit stuck right now with a code.

In fact, I would like to create Vimeo's videos autoplay list on my website using javascript as we can see on youtube.

As you will see on the script below, the click event allows changing the iframe videos. I'd like when my first video in my list of Vimeo's iframe videos end, the second video can start automatically to play as on youtube autoplay.

Please advise.

Here is the link to my script on codepen.io
https://codepen.io/fanhatcha/pen/XQoWdR

```html
      <iframe
       id="playerarea"
       src=""
       width="850"
       height="450"
       frameborder="0"
       allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
       allowfullscreen>
       </iframe>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li vimeourl="https://player.vimeo.com/video/328821953?autoplay=0&loop=1&autopause=0&background=1&responsive=true">
<li vimeourl="https://player.vimeo.com/video/328821360?autoplay=0&loop=1&autopause=0&background=1&responsive=true"> 
</ul>
```

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#playerarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("vimeourl"),
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

'create Vimeo's videos autoplay using javascript?' that just can be!
Vimeo(so is Youtube) are standalone programs. So they'll work only in embed context and won't use JavaScript who can manage and use DOM.
To set a video to autoplay you've to log into the Vimeo application and set it using theirs parameters before sharing it to your own page.
If you could use JavaScript on a program who's not yours it's a flaw and threat for the program...certainly you did agree use and terms of the licence of using Vimeo, so you're bind to their rules.
If you want videos and use them with JavaScript there's the HTML5 API video. By the way it'll require not using a corporate program who will reccord and display the video and use your own server to do that(or any source providing a video files and not a link to the vimeo/youtube application).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please have a look to my code. You will have a better understanding of the issue. https://codepen.io/fanhatcha/pen/XQoWdR

Comment: i've , you set autoplay on a iframe not the video. I've too searched how to set Vimeo video on autoplay and had return you the result of my search... better than just say you : use Google. So you speak of JavaScript but to manage HTML attribute. In none case JS nor HTML5 could manage an external program. So my answer is still the same: it can't be in JavaScript but you have to login Vimeo and set it this way, or use a proper video HTML5 tag and you'll be able to do something. So Vimeo is Vimeo and you've to use Vimeo so no JavaScript or HTML is possible on a video from this source.

Comment: I went through the Vimeo api documentation and I would like the next video to start playing as soon as the first one has ended.

Comment: $(function() {

    //Gets the iframe by id
    var iframe = $('#PLAYER1');
    //Creates a player var using the iframe
    var player = $f(iframe);

    // When the player is ready/loaded, add a finish event listener
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        //Adds an event 'finish' that executes a function 'onFinish' when the video has ended.
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

    //Define the onFinish function that will be called
    function onFinish(id) {
        console.log('THE VIDEO HAS FINISHED PLAYING');
    }

});